# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using nested lists

Tags: java, arraylist, nested, bluej

I'm building a basic battleship-style game in Java and am using nested lists to represent a game grid. However, I keep getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to put down a ship.

The game board has the constructor as follows

```
public Board(){
    theSea = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ShipInterface>>(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < theSea.size(); i++){
        theSea.set(i, new ArrayList<ShipInterface>(10));
    }
}
```

The method for placing the ship is as follows:

```
public void placeShip(ShipInterface ship, Position position, boolean isVertical) throws InvalidPositionException, ShipOverlapException{
    for(int i=0; i<ship.getSize(); i++){
        theSea.get((position.getX()-1) + i).set(position.getY()-1, ship);
    }
}
```

However, I get the error at the line `theSea.get((position.getX()-1) + i).set(position.getY()-1, ship);`

I'm a beginner so sorry if I'm missing some obvious bit of code!

Comment: It would be wise to paste stacktrace here as well and Position class.

Comment: you should paste the part of the code you call `placeShip()` method.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new list, it has size 0 (the value you pass to the `ArrayList` constructor is the *initial capacity* - the *size* is the number of elements it currently contains). So your `Board()` constructor doesn't add anything to theSea - the `for` loop is iterated zero times.

Consequently, `theSea` remains empty, and when you later call `theSea.get(i)` for *any* value of `i`, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So you probably intend to do

```
public Board(){
    theSea = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ShipInterface>>(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        theSea.add(new ArrayList<ShipInterface>(10));
    }
}
```

Note now that `theSea` contains 10 empty lists; i.e. `theSea.get(i)` will return a list of size 0 for `0 <= i < 10`. Thus your `placeShip` method will work, but only as long as each list is populated with `y` ranging from `0` to `9`, in order.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the `for` loop iterating zero times. However, now, I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException when merely trying to initialise the Board. The error comes from `theSea.set(i, new ArrayList<ShipInterface>(10));`

Comment: Is it possible for me to use the same `for` loop, but instead simply use `theSea.add(new ArrayList<ShipInterface>(10));`

Comment: @Brian Yes, should be `add`. Sorry: I had just copied your existing code without thinking it through properly. (`set(...)` replaces an element. You can't replace an element if there are no elements...)